# Undefined when trying to run filter on array

Tags: javascript, filter

I have an array. Pretty simple, like: `[32652,24164]` both of which numbers are stored `productID`s

I have an object storing data associated with each `productID`

```
var products = {
  "products": [{
    "productID": "32652",
    "name": "Playstation 4",
    "price": "109.99"
  }, {
    "productID": "24164",
    "name": "Xbox",
    "price": "129.99"
  }]
};
```

I'm trying to find the associated `name` and `price` in the object along with the `productID` by using `.filter`

I have the following function:

```
function findProductData(productID) {
  var foundProductArray = [];

  var foundProduct = products.products.filter(x => x.productID === productID)[0];

  console.log(foundProduct); // THIS IS COMING BACK UNDEFINED
  if (foundProduct) {
  // This function is never running as the filter is coming back UNDEFINED
    console.log('Something found');
    var foundName = foundProduct.name;
    var foundPrice = foundProduct.price;
    foundProductArray.push(foundName, foundPrice);
    return foundProductArray;
  } else {
    console.log('Nothing found');
  }
}
```

This is the particular line of code that is not working. This should return a result, but it's coming back `undefined`

```
var foundProduct = products.products.filter(x => x.productID === productID)[0];
```

So the function is never running and never finding the associated `name` and `price`.

I've put together a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0bLhr69w/5/)

Comment: `===` means value and type. try `==`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a parseInt. You are trying to strictly compare a string and an int

```
 .filter(x => x.productID === productID)[0]
```

Change that to this

```
.filter(x => parseInt(x.productID) === productID)[0]
```